# ggplot2 for Cluster analysis (non-readible row names)

Tags: r, clustering, ggplot2, agglomerative

I have made a cluster analysis and ended up with dendrogram; however the row names are not readible (made a red rectangle). May I ask if there is way to adjust it?

[image]

```
library("reshape2")
library("purrr")
library("dplyr")
library("dendextend")
dendro <- as.dendrogram(aggl.clust.c)
dendro.col <- dendro %>%
  set("branches_k_color", k = 5, value =   c("darkslategray", "darkslategray4", "darkslategray3", "gold", "gold2")) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 0.6) %>%
  set("labels_colors", 
      value = c("darkslategray")) %>% 
  set("labels_cex", 0.5)
ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dendro.col)
ggplot(ggd1, theme = theme_minimal()) +
  labs(x = "Num. observations", y = "Height", title = "Dendrogram, k = 5")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `theme` to your plot layout

So:

```
library("reshape2")
library("purrr")
library("dplyr")
library("dendextend")
dendro <- as.dendrogram(aggl.clust.c)
dendro.col <- dendro %>%
  set("branches_k_color", k = 5, value =   c("darkslategray", "darkslategray4", "darkslategray3", "gold", "gold2")) %>%
  set("branches_lwd", 0.6) %>%
  set("labels_colors", 
      value = c("darkslategray")) %>% 
  set("labels_cex", 0.5)
ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dendro.col)
ggplot(ggd1, theme = theme_minimal()) + theme(text = element_text(size=20)+
  labs(x = "Num. observations", y = "Height", title = "Dendrogram, k = 5")
```